# Django - Parse URL to get object and save it

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

let's assume we have a endpoint `/user/{user_id}/posts/{post_id}`. I would like Django to be able to automatically parse URL and save model object connected to `user_id` and `post_id`, which I define.

In documentation I have found something like [custom hyperlinked fields](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#custom-hyperlinked-fields) and method `get_url`.
According to documentation:

> The `get_url` method is used to map the object instance to its URL
>   representation.

Is there some method that allows exactly opposite:

> The `get_object_from_url` method is used to map URL representation to its object instance.

Comment: How about [**`get_object(self, view_name, view_args, view_kwargs)`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#custom-hyperlinked-fields) ?

Comment: That is the answer. I've even read that..

Answer (score 0):

The answer is actually [get_object(self, view_name, view_args, view_kwargs)](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#custom-hyperlinked-fields)
which is under method I wrote about in question.